# Module for content publication workflow

Tags: 7, workflows

I am looking for a Drupal 7 module to manage a content publication workflow for different roles. When a user with a certain role creates a content node, it needs to be validated by another user within another role, before it is marked as published. In Drupal 6, I have used the [Workflow](http://drupal.org/project/workflow) module, but it is not available for Drupal 7.

Comment: It is worth noting that the Workflow module does have a Drupal 7 version, now. The Maestro module is not very active, but the Workbench module seems a good idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is now the [Workbench](http://drupal.org/project/workbench) module, for Drupal 7.

> Workbench provides overall improvements for managing content that Drupal does not provide out of the box. Workbench gives us three important solutions:
>
> - a unified and simplified user interface for users who ONLY have to work with content. This decreases training and support time
> - the ability to control who has access to edit any content based on an organization's structure not the web site structure
> - a customizable editorial workflow that integrates with the access control feature described above or works independently on its own

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [Maestro](http://drupal.org/project/maestro) module. 
There is an example workflow to publish content.

Comment: Here is a 13-minute Maestro Admin Tutorial on YouTube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8Cg5iBTCC4

Answer (score 2):

You can use the rules module as described here: http://drupal.org/node/1027546